# Putting CordovaWebView/root view inside a new, parent view

Tags: android, cordova

First, let me start off by saying I'm not well versed in the Android APK. My solution may be solved by reading online documentation. I have tried to read the documentation and have come to the conclusion that I am missing something.

My goal is to take the root view of a PhoneGap application and put it inside of a ViewGroup and set the primary Activity to use the new view group. My reason for this is so I can overlay other views on top of the web view.

When I create the ViewGroup, remove the root view from the activity's content view, add the root view to the ViewGroup, then set the content view to the RootView, I get a blank screen. However, if I add an ImageView to the view group, the image renders fine. This leads me to believe I'm not doing something important with the rootview or webview.

Any advice or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Code:

Activity Code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ((ViewGroup)this.root.getParent()).removeView(this.root);
    this.mainView = new MainView(this.getActivity());
    this.mainView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    this.mainView.addView(this.root);
    this.setContentView(this.mainView);
}
```

MainView Code:

```
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    if(this.getChildCount() == 1){
        this.getChildAt(0).layout(left, top, right, bottom);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

When using viewgroup, you must call measure on the added child:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int width, int height){
    super.onMeasure(width,height);
    if(this.getChildCount() == 1){
        this.getChildAt(0).measure(width,height);
    }
}
```